# storing word in a char array using getline is not working when used inside the loop?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning class in c++. So, I was learning on using array of objects to a class.
When I try to get the name from the user, if the user enters more than a word for name then the following is happening, first time the name is received correctly. But the second time the name is skipped and user is prompted to enter the age without name being entered. I tried to use string instead of char array to get the name even still I get the same problem.
I tried to use `cin.ignore()`. But still I don't find solution to the problem.

**My requirement:**

**1.** To enter multiple words in the name, when user is asked to enter.

**2.** Finally print all data (name and age received from user).

Thanks in advance to all people, who helps!

**CODE:**

```
// Array of objects

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
//#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 30
class employee
{
    char name[SIZE];
    float age;
public:
    void getdata();
    void putdata();
};

void employee::getdata()
{
    cout << "Enter name:";
    cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter age:";
    cin >> age;
}

void employee::putdata()
{
    cout << "Name is " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age is " << age << endl;
}

const int size = 3;

int main()
{
    employee manager[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "\nThe details of the manager " << i+1 << endl;
        manager[i].getdata();
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        cout << "\nManager " << i+1 << endl;
        manager[i].putdata();
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the mistake is rather small but essential:

The call of `cin.ignore()` may be intended for the case where input of `name` exceeds `SIZE - 1` characters. Hence, the call of it should be conditional:

> The failbit flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to s. Note that if the character that follows those (n-1) characters in the input sequence is precisely the delimiting character, it is also extracted and the failbit flag is not set (the extracted sequence was exactly n characters long).

(Taken from [**std::istream::ignore**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).)

For now, I simply excluded it.

The following `cin >> age;` reads a floating point number (because `age` is of type `float`). The following delimiter is left in the input stream. Hence, the next input would receive it which is the name of next manager.

My first idea was to read it with [**`std::istream& std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&);`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). However, after having learnt about [**`std::istream::ignore()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), I modified the sample &nash; it works as well.

Here the modified sample of OP:

```
// Array of objects

#include<iostream>
//#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 30
class employee
{
    char name[SIZE];
    float age;
public:
    void getdata();
    void putdata();
};

void employee::getdata()
{
    cout << "Enter name:";
    cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));
    //EXCLUDED: cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter age:";
    cin >> age;

    //INSERTED:
    // skip rest of line
#if 0 // Tried first:
    string dummy; getline(cin, dummy);
#else // but now use:
    cin.ignore();
#endif // 0
}

void employee::putdata()
{
    cout << "Name is " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age is " << age << endl;
}

const int size = 3;

int main()
{
    employee manager[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "\nThe details of the manager " << i+1 << endl;
        manager[i].getdata();
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        cout << "\nManager " << i+1 << endl;
        manager[i].putdata();
    }

    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/3byhGp).

Input:

```
Michael
32
Jack
48
Joseph
53
```

Output:

```
The details of the manager 1
Enter name:Enter age:
The details of the manager 2
Enter name:Enter age:
The details of the manager 3
Enter name:Enter age:

Manager 1
Name is Michael
Age is 32

Manager 2
Name is Jack
Age is 48

Manager 3
Name is Joseph
Age is 53
```

Note:

For the test on ideone, the input is redirected. Hence, it is not reflected which might look a bit strange. However, the output shows that it has been received by the application properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working fine.
#if 0
    string dummy; getline(cin, dummy);
#else
    cin.ignore();
#endif // 0

what is happening in this part?
in my code i have given cin.ignore(); ,Why is it not working for me?

Comment: Do you ask what it means? It's a common trick to keep old and new code in source. Only, the part between `#else` and `#endif` is "really seen" by compiler.

Comment: The actual fix was to insert the `cin.ignore();` **after** `cin >> age;`. Otherwise, the `\n` (caused by pressing [ENTER] to delimit input) is left in the input stream (`cin`) and will "disturb" input of next manager.

Comment: yes i got it, thanks. The problem is with the enter key that was pressed after giving age.